# Rails Devise complaining "username can't be blank" when username is provided in form and shows in logs with form params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my Rails application (3.2.2), I use Devise for authentication, including Facebook logins.

Everything is working through the Facebook connect process except when my application redirects to the new registration form. We require a few pieces of information aside from what Facebook provides (namely username and password/password confirmation) so the user is dropped on that form to complete it.

When I submit a form to create a new user at the end of the Facebook login process, Devise complains "username cannot be blank" though a string value was provided for username in the form. My first assumption was that the form wasn't labeled properly and the data wasn't making it to the validation. I checked the forms and all was correct. The output in the logs also showed that the value for username was in fact present, but Devise still complains.

I've searched around and I've seen a lot of gists and pastebins with this error but no solutions. Here's the code I think is relevant - please let me know if you want to see anything else.

_form.html.erb

```
<fieldset id="required-user-form-fields">
<h2 class="user-form-header">These we need.</h2><br>

<%= f.label :first_name, class: "user-form-label" %><br>
<%= f.text_field :first_name, size: "30", class: "standard-blue-text-field" %><br>

<%= f.label :email, class: "user-form-label" %><br>
<%= f.text_field :email, class: "standard-blue-text-field", size: "30" %><br>

<%= f.label :username, class: "user-form-label" %><br>
<%= f.text_field :username, class: "standard-blue-text-field#{" disabled" if f.object.persisted?}", size: "30", :disabled => f.object.persisted? %><br>
  <% if f.object.persisted? %>
    <span class="help-block">Username cannot be changed.</span><br>
  <% end %>

<%= f.label :password, class: "user-form-label" %><br>
<%= f.password_field :password, class: "standard-blue-text-field ", size: "30" %><br>
  <% if f.object.persisted? %>
    <span class="help-block">Leave this blank if you don't want your password to change.</span><br>
  <% else %>
    <span class="help-block">Hint: this should be at least 6 characters long.</span><br>
  <% end %>
<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "confirm your password", class: "user-form-label" %><br>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "standard-blue-text-field", size: "30" %><br>

</fieldset>

<fieldset id="optional-user-form-fields">
<h2 class="user-form-header">These are optional.</h2><br>

<%= f.label :zip_code, "Home zip code", class: "user-form-label" %><br>
<%= f.text_field :zip_code, size: "10", class: "standard-blue-text-field" %><br>

<%= f.label :last_name, class: "user-form-label" %><br>
<%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "standard-blue-text-field", size: "30" %><br>

<%= f.label :gender, class: "user-form-label" %><br>
<%= f.select :gender, ['Male', 'Female'], include_blank: true, class: "user-form-gender" %><br>

<%= f.label :birth_month, "When is your birthday?", class: "user-form-label" %><br>
<%= f.select :birth_month, ::Date::MONTHNAMES, {}, class: 'side-by-side' %>
<%= f.select :birth_day, 1..31, {include_blank: true}, class: 'side-by-side' %><br>

<%= f.label :twitter_username, "Are you on Twitter?", class: "user-form-label" %><br>
<%= f.text_field :twitter_username, class: "standard-blue-text-field", size: "30" %><br>

<%= f.label :bio, "Share your cliff note biography in 250 characters or less.", class: "user-form-label" %><br>
<%= f.text_area :bio, class: "standard-blue-text-field", size: "250" %><br>
```

User.rb (exceprt)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username
has_merit

# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable
# and :omniauthable

before_save :create_permalink

devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :lockable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :invitable,
     :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

default_accessible_fields = [:email, :first_name, :last_name, :birth_month,
                           :birth_day, :password, :password_confirmation,
                           :remember_me, :username, :zip_code, :gender, :confirmed_at,
                           :bio, :twitter_username, :permalink] #, :permalink
admin_only_fields = [:admin]

attr_accessible *default_accessible_fields
attr_accessible *(default_accessible_fields + admin_only_fields), :as => :admin

has_many :venue_scores

has_many :tips
has_many :tip_likes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :liked_tips, through: :tip_likes, source: :tip
has_many :lists
has_many :list_likes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :liked_lists, through: :list_likes, source: :list

has_many :my_follows, foreign_key: :follower_id, class_name: 'Follow', dependent: :destroy
has_many :follows, through: :my_follows, source: :followed

has_many :their_follows, foreign_key: :followed_id, class_name: 'Follow', dependent: :destroy
has_many :followers, through: :their_follows

has_many :invitations, :class_name => self.to_s, :as => :invited_by


validates :first_name, presence: true
validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true 
validates :zip_code, numericality: true, length: { is: 5 } unless :has_zip_code?
validates :birth_month, :birth_day, presence: { if: :birthday_provided? }
validates :birth_month, inclusion: { in: ::Date::MONTHNAMES, allow_blank: true }
validates :birth_day, inclusion: { in: 1..31, allow_blank: true }
validate :check_date_for_realness
# Removing username update validation - should check later for conflicts or issues arising from this
# validate :prevent_username_change, on: :update

def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
conditions = warden_conditions.dup
email = conditions.delete(:email)
where(conditions).where(["lower(email) = :value OR lower(username) = :value", { :value => email.strip.downcase }]).first
end
```

Output in logs after form submission

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-03 12:15:57 -0800
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yb9qpXpGfsTJmpL++Kd9S1LPoSVOHA3If1jjKWMTGuY=", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Tom", "email"=>"dhaocew_liangsky_1383438854@tfbnw.net", "username"=>"thomas", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "zip_code"=>"", "last_name"=>"Liangsky", "gender"=>"Male", "birth_month"=>"", "birth_day"=>"", "twitter_username"=>"", "bio"=>""}}
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
User Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'dhaocew_liangsky_1383438854@tfbnw.net' LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'dhaocew_liangsky_1383438854@tfbnw.net' LIMIT 1
User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = '' LIMIT 1
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'dhaocew_liangsky_1383438854@tfbnw.net' LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Rendered devise/registrations/_form.html.erb (4.1ms)
Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.slim within layouts/application (6.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 113ms (Views: 28.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

RegistrationsController.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def after_sign_up_path_for(devise_resource)
    edit_user_registration_path
  end

  #def account_update_params
  #  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update)
  #end

end
```

Comment: maybe uniqueness validation is failed (not presence)?  Check if the same username does not exist in the DB.

Comment: @gotva I've had the same problem trying to set up a few different test users so I didn't suspect that was the problem. I did run all of the usernames in console, though, just to check. Unfortunately no duplicates so that isn't the source of the problem.

Comment: strange situation... I do not have really good idea. I can only suggest to open `RegistrationsController#create` from the gem and debug there. It seems to me that smth remove (or ignore) `username` but I can not imagine what and where can do it.

Comment: Are you overriding the registrations controller?

Comment: @trh I am, but only for a minor addition. I've added it to the bottom of my question above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved for the root cause. A method used as part of facebook authentication:

```
def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"]
        user.first_name = data["first_name"]
        user.last_name = data["last_name"]
        #user.username = data["username"]
        user.gender = data["gender"].capitalize
        user.facebook_id = data["id"]
        user.skip_confirmation!
      end
    end
  end
```

was calling for user.username on the data which was derived from the facebook authentication. We don't request username as part of the Facebook scope so it doesn't exist, but the app was ignoring the form data because of this call in the controller. You'll see I've commented it out and all seems to be working with test users now.